# bootstrap slider on left half of page

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, templates, responsive-design, slider

Is it possible to create a page in bootstrap with slider on only left half of the page and some text on right half of the page?

Will the website/page still be responsive?

If there is any such theme already, please suggest. (WordPress or bootstrap responsive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a problem at all. I suggest you take a look at the bootstrap documentation, specifically at the [Grid section](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). It describes how to build the sites grid, which (by itself) will be responsive. If the column content behaves nicely when the viewport size changes, depends on the content you put in there.

For the slider, take a look at [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) which is responsive.

Here is a quick bootstrap grid example for 2 columns next to each other that should give you an idea of how to do this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            Left Column
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            Right Column
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```